# Propagating hostname to router

Tags: linux, linux-mint

How do you propagate changes to your hostname from your Linux machine (I am using Linux Mint 13) to your router (I am using DG834Gv2)?

I changed the hostname in /etc/hostname and restarted. The router still resolves the old hostname to my IP address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here, depending on your setup:

If your machine is using DHCP to get an IP from the router, it is possible that the router is taking the hostname from the DHCP request and filling its internal DNS with that. In this case you have to release and obtain again an IP from the router. You can accomplish this by reconfiguring the interface (wlan0, eth0). Unluckily I don't know what tools LinuxMint uses for reconfiguring the interfaces, so you will have to figure it out by yourself.

The other option is that the router's internal DNS is filled by configuration, either from the DHCP section or from a dedicated DNS section. Check your router's configuration. I don't know the model you mention either, but it is possible that you will have to reboot the router.

Comment: Machine is using DHCP to get an IP. Tried `dhclient -r` and then `dhclient` with no luck.

There's no dedicated DNS section as far as I can tell by looking at the admin interface or reading the docs.